# How to select multiple nodes from XML with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the XPath syntax that returns multiple nodes from XML?

Say I have XML like so:

```
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <Name>
      <FirstName>Andre</FirstName>
      <LastName>Levy</LastName>
    </Name>
    <DOB>
      <Year>1970</Year>
      <Month>5</Month>
      <Day>13</Day>
    </DOB>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <Name>
      <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
      <LastName>Fisher</LastName>
    </Name>
    <DOB>
      <Year>1983</Year>
      <Month>7</Month>
      <Day>24</Day>
    </DOB>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

What XPath will give me:

```
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <FirstName>Andre</FirstName>
    <Year>1970</Year>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <Year>1983</Year>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I tried:    `//FirstName | //Year`

But that only yields:

```
<FirstName>Andre</FirstName>
<FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
<Year>1970</Year>
<Year>1983</Year>
```

What gives?

Comment: Not sure about XPath 2, but not possible in XPath 1. You can extract parts of the original document, but you can't reshuffle it.

Comment: Sounds like a XSLT task. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914843/remove-all-nodes-from-xml-excluding-specific-nodes-using-xslt and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838074/xslt-copy-certain-nodes-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **You *can* select multiple nodes in XPath, but you *cannot* re-arrange XML in the manner exhibited in your requested output.**

**Also note:**

1. Your sample XML is not well-formed; it must have a single root
   element.
2. You can indeed select multiple nodes as your title question asks
   using the union operator `|` you suggest, however...
3. Your desired XML is not available for ***selection***, which XPath
   does, but it could be constructed via ***transformation***, which XSLT does
   (provided you're willing to wrap the desired XML in a single
   enclosing root element).

Comment: Ok, I've added the single root element. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that covers #1, but that's the easy part; understand that #3 is the hard part.  You need to use XSLT or another language hosting XPath when you want to ***rearrange*** that which you select via XPath.