# XPATH 1.0 construct a new xml document out of original one depending on condition

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml document like this one:

```
<dataContainerList>
    <Container>
        <LocalDataContainer>
            <file>InputFile3</file>
        </LocalDataContainer>
    </Container>

    <Container>
        <LocalDataContainer>
            <file>InputFile2</file>
        </LocalDataContainer>
    </Container>

    <Container>
        <LocalDataContainer>
            <file>InputFile3</file>
        </LocalDataContainer>
    </Container>
</dataContainerList>
```

and I want to filter out all the **Container** with file **name = InputFile3**

**Means**: I want to create a new **dataContainereList** with the only the first and the third container.

Is that possible with one `XPATH1.0` command? Cannot use `XSL` or something, just plain `XPath`
and this should work with arbitrary **dataContainerList**.

Comment: of course easiest would be to remove the nodes that do not qualify , but xpath 1.0 does not offer xml updates

Comment: No, XPath alone can *select* nodes, not *create* or *rearrange* nodes.  See similar question and answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26320082/290085).

Comment: any idea how a XSLT would look like? i am not proficient with xslt at all, but i need to transform this, the root element of this xml is datacontainerreferencelist, so i can transform and assign the new list to a variable

Comment: XSLT would be trivial -- just a small variation of the identity transformation.  I'll show you in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like rather than filter out `Containers` named "InputFile3", you actually want to *select* such containers.

You can use a simple variation of the identity transformation in XSLT to copy everything to the output *except* those `Containers` not named "InputFile3".

**This input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile2</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
</Containers>
```

**Applied to this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Container[LocalDataContainer/file != 'InputFile3']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Would yield this output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
</Containers>
```

Comment: thanks, and now how can i include this in my BPEL process? where do i put the xslt file and how does the assign operation have to look like?

Comment: i want to assign this new list to a variable of type datacontainerreferencelist(defined with xsd, which has exactly the structure of the given xml)

Comment: Answer to your original question: XPath alone can't do this.   Answer to second question (in comments of question): XSLT can as shown in this answer above.  Answers to additional questions: Please create new questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. XPath allows you to filter `Container` elements, but has no facility to output or update the results.

For that you might use a XQuery 1.0 processor. For instance this works:

```
<dataContainerList> {
    doc("file.xml")//Container[./LocalDataContainer/file != 'InputFile2']
}
</dataContainerList>
```

Comment: ok, in case i used doXslTransform, would that work? i need to assign the new list to another variable in BPEL and assign can only handle one node, that is why i initially wanted to transform the whole output to a string and then assign, but that does not work