# How to apply XSLT transformation in a BPEL process

Tags: xml, xslt, bpel

From an [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023375/290085), I have this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile2</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
</Containers>
```

Which when given to this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Container[LocalDataContainer/file != 'InputFile3']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces this output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
  <Container>
    <LocalDataContainer>
      <file>InputFile3</file>
    </LocalDataContainer>
  </Container>
</Containers>
```

How can the XSLT be included technically into BPEL process? I am using Eclipse BPEL Designer
where to put the XSLT file?  Is the XSLT saved as .xsl file which is then just imported into project folder?  And how does the Assign have to look like?  I want to assign the new list to a variable of type datacontainerreferencelist (defined with XSD, which has exactly the structure of the given input XML, root element is `Containers`)

Comment: i created a ConListTransform.xsl file and copied it into my project, now i get the error...Resource ConListTransform.xsl does not exist

Comment: Have you looked at [the BPEL spec.](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html#_Toc164738498)? The section on assignment has a few examples on the usage of XSLT. Basically said, there is a `doXslTransform` XPath function which you can invoke in a `from`.

Comment: yes i have, i usually try to do things on my own before i write on here.... this is how my assign looks like                 <bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from>
                    
                    
                    <![CDATA[bpel:doXslTransform('ListTransform.xsl', $containerList)]]>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="FilteredcontainerList"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>

Comment: i have copied and pasted ListTransform.xsl into webapps/ode/WEB-INF\processes and i have pasted it into my bpel project in Eclipse...but when i run the project i get Java error...NullPointerException, ListTransfrom.xsl does not exist

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problem comes from exactly. I have a BPEL process using an XSL-transformation running on ODE 1.3.6. The XSL is located on the same level as the .bpel file in the deployment package. The call to the transformation looks like this: <from>bpel:doXslTransform("blabla.xslt", $SomeVariable)</from>

Comment: I don't use Eclipse ;) I just have all the files in one directory, build a zip of that directory and put that into /WEB-INF/processes

Comment: Unfortunately no, I never liked the Eclipse wizards for this. I created and tested the xslt in IntelliJ.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea how to get doXSLtransform to work in APache ODE? still stuck with this. I keep getting error that my script does not exist, although it is in the project folder