# Get XSLT to work in Apache ODE

Tags: eclipse, xslt, bpel

I am asking this question because I could not find any kind of documentation online about how to integrate XSLT in a ODE BPEL process.

Just the BPEL spec gives a little example about how the code should look like
but nothing else.

Where do I have to create the XSL file within Eclipse and where to save it?

Here is what I do: I right-click on my project in Eclipse and create a new XSL file, write the code and save it.

when i run the BPEL process i get the error message:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_45
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


Error
Sun Nov 23 14:28:29 CET 2014
Resource '/Project1/TransformXML/NewStylesheet.xsl' does not exist.
```

and there is no error stack. 
So what am I doing wrong, anybody on here who is proficient in XSLT and could give a hint?

Comment: Does `/Project1/TransformXML/NewStylesheet.xsl` exist on your file system?

Comment: yes, by creating it in Eclipse and saving it right in my project it exists. i looked up the project folder and it is there, like any other WSDL or XSD-file that the BPEL process needs for execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply XSLT transformation in a BPEL process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023842/how-to-apply-xslt-transformation-in-a-bpel-process)